# How to Upload text file using Play framework?

Tags: java, playframework

I am looking for some tutorials or snippet to Upload a text file using Play framework. actually from the Net all I could get is pictures/images upload. But, I could not get for text files.

Even if I am able to upload the files through the snippets all around the web, I could not able to read the contents of the file in server to process.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should accept some questions/answers first.

Comment: @Zenklys, I have tried but could not able. Please help if you have some links.

Comment: @ChennaiROR you have 1 accepted answer, you know how to do it. If not, at the top there is a help menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text file upload is no different from image upload or any other file upload.

As per Play documentation http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/5things:

```
<form action="@{Texts.uploadTextFile()}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="file" id="textFile" name="textFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And in controller:

```
public static void uploadTextFile(String title, File textFile) {
   String[] lines = FileUtils.readLines(textFile);
}
```

Comment: does it work with IE? my code looks ~  the same, and **IE9** tries to... download or open the file that I'm uploading...